# Vue js with Bootstrap, navbar menu don't work

Tags: vue.js, navbar, boot

I'm implements on Vue js a navbar menu, it's responsive, it work perfectly for desktop, but when I test the responsive mode the menu don't work, this is the button toggle:

```
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#sidebarMenu"
          aria-controls="sidebarMenu"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
```

and on my sidebar I have:

```
<nav id="sidebarMenu" class="collapse d-lg-block sidebar collapse bg-white">
```

you can see the reference `sidebarMenu` so, I don't know what's wrong? I load my code on [CodesandBox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-tharp-m2pq3d?file=/src/App.vue:47-123)

you can check and tell me what's wrong?? please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use vue directives instead of d**ata-toggle** and data-target ... here is how it should be done in vue :

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- Button to toggle the sidebar -->
    <button
    class="navbar-toggler"
    type="button"
    @click="toggleSidebar"
    >
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav
    id="sidebarMenu"
    :class="{ 'collapse': !sidebarOpen, 'd-lg-block': sidebarOpen, 'bg-white': sidebarOpen }"
    >
    <!-- Sidebar content -->
    </nav>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data() {
    return {
    sidebarOpen: true, // Initial state, you can set it to false if you want it closed by default
    };
},
methods: {
    toggleSidebar() {
    // Toggle the sidebarOpen state
    this.sidebarOpen = !this.sidebarOpen;
    },
},
};
</script>
```

Comment: I got you, hmmmmm so I should implement the logic using javascript, thanks bro! it's working now.

Comment: welcome , could you mark it as correct answer please ? :`D

Comment: yes!!! of course